# Set VerticalAlignment in DrawText

Tags: c#, wpf, vertical-alignment, drawtext

I'm using `DrawText` to draw `FormattedText` on Visual Layer. Now I'm using the code below to define the formatted text and I'm able to set the `TextAlignment` to `Center`. But what about the `VerticalAlignment`? As you can see in the image below the center of the text is not on the **centerpoint** which is shown with a red dot here.

**The part where I'm defining the `FormattedText` :**

```
var ft = new FormattedText("A",
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface("Verdana"),
    36, Brushes.Yellow);

ft.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
```

**The part where I'm drawing the text:**

```
var centerpoint = new Point(0,0);
dc.DrawText(ft, centerpoint);
```

**Here is final result:**

[image]

I want the middle of the text to lie on the center of the circle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well Ok it seems I was able to solve this. It is not that hard. I'll post the answer here for future reference. And It might help other people too.

As it seems there is not such a thing as `VerticalAlignment` for a `FormattedText` so we need to calculate and position it ourselves. Since we can get the `Height` property of the formatted text. We can easily align the text like this:

```
dc.DrawText(ft, new Point(centerpoint.X, centerpoint.Y- ft.Height/2));
```

[image: Here is the result]

Answer (score 0):

Last version of `FormattedText` with `PixelsPerDip.`

```
Typeface typeFace = new Typeface(new FontFamily("Segoe UI"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText("Bodrum Bodrum", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeFace, 14, Brushes.Black, VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip);

Point textPoint = new Point(100, 100);
drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, textPoint);
```